# Can We Ask Questions About CMS Glitches?

Tags: discussion, questions

Are we allowed to ask questions about CMS glitches on Stack Overflow? I want to ask about a WordPress glitch, but I'm not sure how it will be received by the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the nature of your question, I'd say.

If you're sure it's a glitch and want to avoid it, you should report it on the [WordPress bug tracker](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/).

If you **have not** written any code yourself, have a problem that you want to fix, and only suspect it's a glitch, you should ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [WordPress SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

If you **have** written some code yourself, have a problem and only suspect it's a glitch, asking on StackOverflow should be fine.

If you know it's a glitch and you want to understand its cause and nature and/or how it could be exploited, asking on StackOverflow should be fine too.

Comment: Naturally, the question must be of acceptable quality.

Comment: @Deduplicator I took that for granted, since if that's not given, the answer to "can I ask..." will always be no. It must also not be offensive or contain spam.

Comment: I decided to report my problem on the main WordPress site anyway. Thanks for the advice, guys.